# Visa refusal / appeal from German consulate, Karachi

Tags: germany, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I applied for a Schengen visa (through the German consulate, Karachi) on June 19, 2017 showing travel from Frankfurt to Karachi (Sep 9, 2017) and Copenhagen to Karachi (Sep 23, 2017). My visa rejection (dated July 4, 2017) was handed to me on July 11, 2017 stating reason No. 9: “intention to leave the territory of the member states before the expiry of the visa applied for could not be ascertained”. I submitted my remonstrant letter (via email and post) on July 20, 2017 to the German consulate, Karachi.

July 25, 2017, I get a call from the German consulate asking me to submit my passport for visa. I told them that my passport has now gone for visa application of Turkey and I don’t know when will it be back. The lady on the phone (from the German consulate) verbally reconfirmed my travel dates from me and said that the consulate has reopened my application on July 26, 2017, and after Aug 7, 2017 I can submit the passport for visa (since my travel dates are still not too close enough). I verbally asked her if I am getting the visa after the remonstrant and she replied: “yes you are getting the visa”.

My questions:

1. Why did they have to reopen the application after the remonstrant. If is a normal procedure?
2. What are my chances of getting the tourist visa now for Germany? Or is a rejection still possible?

Comment: Nobody can give you an answer except the German embassy!

Comment: Wow. Apparently you're in one of the ultra-rare cases where appealing an averse visa decision has the desired effect -- and then you're complaining about THAT? There's just no pleasing some people.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. The lady said “yes you are getting the visa”. and you are asking us what your chances are?  I don't get it.  :(    Close voting as unclear, sorry...  please clarify.